# Add some numbers in a figure generated with python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

it's my first post ever on stackoverflow so please be gentle.

Here is my issue:
i found on a website a very nice python script, that i had to slightly modify to fit my needs and now i would like to modify it once again but i don't know how to

First the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bullseye_plot(ax, data, segBold=None, cmap=None, norm=None):
    """
    Bullseye representation for the left ventricle.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : axes
    data : list of int and float
        The intensity values for each of the 17 segments
    segBold: list of int, optional
        A list with the segments to highlight
    cmap : ColorMap or None, optional
        Optional argument to set the desired colormap
    norm : Normalize or None, optional
        Optional argument to normalize data into the [0.0, 1.0] range


    Notes
    -----
    This function create the 17 segment model for the left ventricle according
    to the American Heart Association (AHA) [1]_

    References
    ----------
    .. [1] M. D. Cerqueira, N. J. Weissman, V. Dilsizian, A. K. Jacobs,
        S. Kaul, W. K. Laskey, D. J. Pennell, J. A. Rumberger, T. Ryan,
        and M. S. Verani, "Standardized myocardial segmentation and
        nomenclature for tomographic imaging of the heart",
        Circulation, vol. 105, no. 4, pp. 539-542, 2002.
    """
    if segBold is None:
        segBold = []

    linewidth = 2
    data = np.array(data).ravel()

    if cmap is None:
        cmap = plt.cm.viridis

    if norm is None:
        norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())

    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 768)
    r = np.linspace(0, 1, 4)

    # Create the bound for the segment 17
    for i in range(r.shape[0]):
        ax.plot(theta, np.repeat(r[i], theta.shape), '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Create the bounds for the segments  1-12
    for i in range(6):
        theta_i = i*60*np.pi/180
        ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[1], 1], '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Create the bounds for the segments 13-16
    for i in range(4):
        theta_i = i*90*np.pi/180 - 45*np.pi/180
        ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Fill the segments 1-6
    r0 = r[2:4]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 128, axis=1).T
    for i in range(6):
        # First segment start at 60 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*128:i*128+128] + 60*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((128, 2))*data[i]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if i+1 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[2], r[3]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[2], r[3]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    # Fill the segments 7-12
    r0 = r[1:3]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 128, axis=1).T
    for i in range(6):
        # First segment start at 60 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*128:i*128+128] + 60*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((128, 2))*data[i+6]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if i+7 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[1], r[2]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[1], r[2]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    # Fill the segments 13-16
    r0 = r[0:2]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 192, axis=1).T
    for i in range(4):
        # First segment start at 45 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*192:i*192+192] + 45*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((192, 2))*data[i+12]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if i+13 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])

# Create the fake data
data = np.array(range(17)) + 1

# Make a figure and axes with dimensions as desired.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8), nrows=1, ncols=1,
                       subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Left Ventricle Bulls Eyes (AHA)')

# Set the colormap and norm to correspond to the data for which
# the colorbar will be used.
cmap = mpl.cm.viridis
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=17)

# Create the 17 segment model
bullseye_plot(ax, data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax.set_title('Bulls Eye (AHA)')

plt.show()
```

It produce what we call a bulleye map, see the output produced:
[Bulleye map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJkRt.png)

What i want to do is quite straightforward to explain:

-i would like to add properly, nicely, a number or two numbers (max) in each segment (in this picture, there are 16 segments).

-Depending on the value of the number (when there is only one number), i would like to be able to associate each segment to a different shade/color. For instance, if i have "2", the color of the associated segment will be red. If i have "4", the color of the associated segment might also be red but darker. Something along these lines.

If such a thing is not possible, at least i would like to have a different color depending on the number associated to a given segment.

I am not that knowledgable in python so i don't know how to do it and my questions are so specific that i don't really know where to look for an answer.
If you could help me, i would be really grateful.

PS: Also, if you think the code could be improved somehow (or that there are some useless parts), please tell me so.

Thank you in advance.

PS: in order to give credit to the one who created the code in the fist place, here is the original link
[How to generate bulleye map](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/leftventricle_bulleye.html)

So far, i did something similar with Latex, here is the picture i obtained when they are 2 numbers for each segment. I hope it will make it easier to "picture" what i would like.
[Bulleye map - LateX version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SHNz.png)

Update: by combining the accepted answer and some idea from the original script, i finally got exactly what i wanted.
Here is the script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def bullseye_plot(ax, data, segBold=None, cmap=None, norm=None, labels=[], labelProps={}):

    if segBold is None:
        segBold = []

    linewidth = 2
    data = np.array(data).ravel()

    if cmap is None:
        cmap = plt.cm.viridis

    if norm is None:
        norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())

    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 768)
    r = np.linspace(0, 1, 4)

    # Create the bound for the segment 17
    for i in range(r.shape[0]):
        ax.plot(theta, np.repeat(r[i], theta.shape), '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Create the bounds for the segments  1-12
    for i in range(6):
        theta_i = i*60*np.pi/180
        ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[1], 1], '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Create the bounds for the segments 13-16
    for i in range(4):
        theta_i = i*90*np.pi/180 - 45*np.pi/180
        ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Fill the segments 1-6
    r0 = r[2:4]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 128, axis=1).T
    for i in range(6):
        # First segment start at 60 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*128:i*128+128] + 60*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((128, 2))*data[i]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if labels:
            ax.annotate(labels[i], xy=(theta0[0,0]+30*np.pi/180,np.mean(r[2:4])), ha='center', va='center', **labelProps)
        if i+1 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[2], r[3]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[2], r[3]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    # Fill the segments 7-12
    r0 = r[1:3]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 128, axis=1).T
    for i in range(6):
        # First segment start at 60 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*128:i*128+128] + 60*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((128, 2))*data[i+6]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if labels:
            ax.annotate(labels[i+6], xy=(theta0[0,0]+30*np.pi/180,np.mean(r[1:3])), ha='center', va='center', **labelProps)
        if i+7 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[1], r[2]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[1], r[2]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    # Fill the segments 13-16
    r0 = r[0:2]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 192, axis=1).T
    for i in range(4):
        # First segment start at 45 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*192:i*192+192] + 45*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((192, 2))*data[i+12]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if labels:
            ax.annotate(labels[i+12], xy=(theta0[0,0]+45*np.pi/180,np.mean(r[0:2])), ha='center', va='center', **labelProps)
        if i+13 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])


# Create the fake data
labels = ['1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9',
 '10',
 '11',
 '12',
 '13',
 '14',
 '15',
 '16']

data=[]
for i in range(len(labels)):
    x=int(labels[i])
    data.append(x)

# Make a figure and axes with dimensions as desired.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8), nrows=1, ncols=1,
                       subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Left Ventricle Bulls Eyes (AHA)')

# Create the axis for the colorbars
axl = fig.add_axes([0.14, 0.15, 0.2, 0.05])

# Set the colormap and norm to correspond to the data for which
# the colorbar will be used.
cmap = mpl.cm.viridis
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(data), vmax=max(data))

# ColorbarBase derives from ScalarMappable and puts a colorbar
# in a specified axes, so it has everything needed for a
# standalone colorbar.  There are many more kwargs, but the
# following gives a basic continuous colorbar with ticks
# and labels.
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axl, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
                                orientation='horizontal')
cb1.set_label('Some Units')


# Create the 16 segment model
bullseye_plot(ax, data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, labels=labels, labelProps={'size':15, "weight":'bold'})
ax.set_title('Bulls Eye (AHA)')

plt.show()
```

As for the result, here it is
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Dwq.png)

Comment: Sure, i would like to just add numbers on the figure itself.
I have a file that contains 16 numbers and i want to have, at the end, the same figure with 1 number at the "center" of each segment.
I did the same by generating a latex file, i will add it for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified the code to add labels in the (approximate) center of the cells. You can pass an array of labels (as strings), and a dictionary of [any parameters accepted by matplotlib's Text](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) to adjust the appearance of the labels.

As for the color of the cells, they are determined by the `data` and the colormap.
In your original code, you had a linear colormap (`viridis`). Instead, you can generate your own colorbar using `ListedColormap` and map each color to a specific value in data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bullseye_plot(ax, data, segBold=None, cmap=None, norm=None, labels=[], labelProps={}):
    """
    Bullseye representation for the left ventricle.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : axes
    data : list of int and float
        The intensity values for each of the 17 segments
    segBold: list of int, optional
        A list with the segments to highlight
    cmap : ColorMap or None, optional
        Optional argument to set the desired colormap
    norm : Normalize or None, optional
        Optional argument to normalize data into the [0.0, 1.0] range


    Notes
    -----
    This function create the 17 segment model for the left ventricle according
    to the American Heart Association (AHA) [1]_

    References
    ----------
    .. [1] M. D. Cerqueira, N. J. Weissman, V. Dilsizian, A. K. Jacobs,
        S. Kaul, W. K. Laskey, D. J. Pennell, J. A. Rumberger, T. Ryan,
        and M. S. Verani, "Standardized myocardial segmentation and
        nomenclature for tomographic imaging of the heart",
        Circulation, vol. 105, no. 4, pp. 539-542, 2002.
    """
    if segBold is None:
        segBold = []

    linewidth = 2
    data = np.array(data).ravel()

    if cmap is None:
        cmap = plt.cm.viridis

    if norm is None:
        norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=data.min(), vmax=data.max())

    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 768)
    r = np.linspace(0, 1, 4)

    # Create the bound for the segment 17
    for i in range(r.shape[0]):
        ax.plot(theta, np.repeat(r[i], theta.shape), '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Create the bounds for the segments  1-12
    for i in range(6):
        theta_i = i*60*np.pi/180
        ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[1], 1], '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Create the bounds for the segments 13-16
    for i in range(4):
        theta_i = i*90*np.pi/180 - 45*np.pi/180
        ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth)

    # Fill the segments 1-6
    r0 = r[2:4]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 128, axis=1).T
    for i in range(6):
        # First segment start at 60 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*128:i*128+128] + 60*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((128, 2))*data[i]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if labels:
            ax.annotate(labels[i], xy=(theta0[0,0]+30*np.pi/180,np.mean(r[2:4])), ha='center', va='center', **labelProps)
        if i+1 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[2], r[3]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[2], r[3]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    # Fill the segments 7-12
    r0 = r[1:3]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 128, axis=1).T
    for i in range(6):
        # First segment start at 60 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*128:i*128+128] + 60*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((128, 2))*data[i+6]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if labels:
            ax.annotate(labels[i+6], xy=(theta0[0,0]+30*np.pi/180,np.mean(r[1:3])), ha='center', va='center', **labelProps)
        if i+7 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[1], r[2]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[1], r[2]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    # Fill the segments 13-16
    r0 = r[0:2]
    r0 = np.repeat(r0[:, np.newaxis], 192, axis=1).T
    for i in range(4):
        # First segment start at 45 degrees
        theta0 = theta[i*192:i*192+192] + 45*np.pi/180
        theta0 = np.repeat(theta0[:, np.newaxis], 2, axis=1)
        z = np.ones((192, 2))*data[i+12]
        ax.pcolormesh(theta0, r0, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        if labels:
            ax.annotate(labels[i+12], xy=(theta0[0,0]+45*np.pi/180,np.mean(r[0:2])), ha='center', va='center', **labelProps)
        if i+13 in segBold:
            ax.plot(theta0, r0, '-k', lw=linewidth+2)
            ax.plot(theta0[0], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)
            ax.plot(theta0[-1], [r[0], r[1]], '-k', lw=linewidth+1)

    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])

# Create the fake data
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]
labels = ['label 1',
 'label 2',
 'label 3',
 'label 4',
 'label 5',
 'label 6',
 'label 7',
 'label 8',
 'label 9',
 'label 10',
 'label 11',
 'label 12',
 'label 13',
 'label 14',
 'label 15',
 'label 16',
 'label 17']

# Make a figure and axes with dimensions as desired.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8), nrows=1, ncols=1,
                       subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Left Ventricle Bulls Eyes (AHA)')

# Set the colormap and norm to correspond to the data for which
# the colorbar will be used.
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['xkcd:dusty purple',
 'xkcd:light aquamarine',
 'xkcd:pale salmon',
 'xkcd:dusty orange',
 'xkcd:sapphire',
 'xkcd:azure'])
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=6)

# Create the 17 segment model
bullseye_plot(ax, data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, labels=labels, labelProps={'size':15, "weight":'bold'})
ax.set_title('Bulls Eye (AHA)')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This...This is perfect!
Thank you so much!

Comment: And on second thought, i would like to add that the numerotation you chose make it even easier for me to "convert" my data since you follow exacly the classical numerotation for the AHA segmentation.
Thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks, but all credits must go to the original author, whoever they are. I have fixed a small bug in the positioning of the labels in the center. I've updated my answer with the corrected code.

Comment: Indeed, you are right but i wasn't aware of that before actually adding my own data.
Great! It didn't bother me that much but it is indeed even better know, i will take it into account.

Comment: I have updated my answer and combined your ideas with some from the original script and now i have exactly what i wanted to begin with!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for starts at line 55 :

```
for i in range(6):
    theta_i = i*60*np.pi/180
    ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[1], 1], '-k', lw=linewidth)
```

Notice the number 60, that seems to be the width of the segment. You can modify this to something like :

```
for i in range(6):
    print "Enter value : "
    read num
    theta_i = i*num*np.pi/180
    ax.plot([theta_i, theta_i], [r[1], 1], '-k', lw=linewidth)
```

I do not have the libraries you are using so I cannot test this. But hope you find this useful.

PS. Make sure that sum( num1 ... num6 ) = 360

Answer (score 1):

You can add that to the end of the `bullseye_plot` function

```
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
r = [1/6,3/6,5/6]

    count = 0
    for t in [0,1,2]:
        if t == 0:
            theta = [0,np.pi/2,np.pi,-np.pi/2]
            for i in range(4):
                ax.text(theta[i],r[0] ,str(data[count]),horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',fontsize=20, color='white' )
                count+=1
        if t == 1:
            theta = np.arange(6)/6*2*np.pi+2*np.pi/12
            for i in range(6):
                ax.text(theta[i],r[1] ,str(data[count]),horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',fontsize=20, color='white')
                count+=1
        if t == 2:
            theta = np.arange(6)/6*2*np.pi+2*np.pi/12
            for i in range(6):
                ax.text(theta[i],r[2] ,str(data[count]),horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',fontsize=20, color='white')
                count+=1
```

This is obviously not optimized but it could help for the idea